# Drawing planes and vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, 3d

What would be the best way to create diagrams similar to those attached? I have briefly looked over the `tikz-3dplot` package but it doesn't seem very convenient for my purposes. When I'm dealing with one plane, a parallelogram using `tikz` or `tkz-euclid` does the job but I don't think it would be the best choice here.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Edit (to make things more concise): How can I replicate the diagram. I'm not sure about how to draw the two intersecting planes.

Comment: Welcom to TeX SX . Can you show us what  you tried, please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is an option using the Ti*k*Z libraries:

- `3d` for the options `canvas is ...` that allow you to draw in a plane parallel to the coordinate planes. Also you can `rotate around` any axis those planes.
- `perspective` for choosing the `3d view`.

I made a couple of styles too, one for each plane and other for the vectors.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\pgfmathsetmacro\anglelp{-5}  % rotation of light plane
\pgfmathsetmacro\angledp{-50} % rotation of dark  plane
\tikzset
{
  light plane/.style={rotate around x=\anglelp, canvas is xz plane at y=0,draw=cyan,fill=cyan!5},
   dark plane/.style={rotate around x=\angledp,canvas is xy plane at z=0,draw=cyan,fill=cyan!25},
  vector/.style={rotate around x=#1, canvas is yz plane at x=0,-latex,thick,draw=blue}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{20},line join=round]
% planes
\draw[dark plane]  (-2,-2) rectangle (2,0);
\draw[light plane] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,4);
\draw[dark plane]  (-2, 0) rectangle (2,4);
% vectors
\draw[vector=\anglelp] (0,1) coordinate (o1) --++ (4,0) coordinate (n1) node[below] {$n_1$};
\draw[vector=\angledp] (1,0) coordinate (o2) --++ (0,4) coordinate (n2) node[above] {$n_2$};
\coordinate (i) at (intersection of o1--n1 and o2--n2); % intersection of both vectors
% angles
\draw[dashed] (o1) -- (0,0,0) -- (o2);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0] (90+\anglelp:0.5)        arc (90+\anglelp:\angledp:0.5)      node[midway,right] {$\theta$};
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0] (i) ++ (90+\angledp:0.5) arc (90+\angledp:\anglelp:0.5)      node[midway,right] {$\alpha$};
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=2] (270+\anglelp:0.5)       arc (270+\anglelp:360+\angledp:0.5) node[midway,below] {$\alpha$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]